# CSS 3D transform rotate: origin is moving on first transition

Tags: css, transform, css-transitions

I have created a 3D carouse. It arranges content in a horizontal circle which rotates on the y axis by applying `transform: rotateY` and `translate` to the parent.

The problem is that the transform-origin seems to move, but only on the first transition. On subsequent rotations the origin stays in the center as it should.

Reproduced in:

- Chrome 38 OSX
- Chrome 38 Win7
- Firefox 30 OSX
- Safari 7.0.6 OSX

IE 10 (Win7) has a different bug: it rotates around the x axis on the first transition.

Pen: http://codepen.io/tricki/full/BGuwo

Click on "Rotate": The origin moves during the transition
Click on "Rotate again": The origin doesn't move
Click on "Rotate" again: The origin doesn't move

At first I thought it was a browser bug but the fact that Firefox has the same problem made me sceptical.
Can anyone see the mistake I made or confirm that this is in fact a browser bug?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="card card-1"></div>
    <div class="card card-2"></div>
    <div class="card card-3"></div>
    <div class="card card-4"></div>
    <div class="card card-5"></div>
    <div class="card card-6"></div>
    <div class="card card-7"></div>
    <div class="card card-8"></div>
    <div class="card card-9"></div>
    <div class="card card-10"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#parent {
    background: red;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;

    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: center center -461px;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, -461px);
}

#parent.active {
    transition: transform 5s linear;
    transform:rotateY(-144deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, -461px);
}

#parent.active2 {
    transition: transform 5s linear;
    transform:rotateY(-288deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, -461px);
}

.card {
    background: blue;
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: absolute;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    opacity: .5;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.card-1  { transform: rotateY( 0deg )   translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
.card-2  { transform: rotateY( 36deg )  translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
.card-3  { transform: rotateY( 72deg )  translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
.card-4  { transform: rotateY( 108deg ) translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
.card-5  { transform: rotateY( 144deg ) translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
.card-6  { transform: rotateY( 180deg ) translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
.card-7  { transform: rotateY( 216deg ) translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
.card-8  { transform: rotateY( 252deg ) translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
.card-9  { transform: rotateY( 288deg ) translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
.card-10 { transform: rotateY( 324deg ) translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
```

Comment: The only origin you have is on the parent and that never changes...

Comment: I know, that's why I don't understand why it does change during the transition.

Answer (score 0):

Removing your `-461px` origin shift and Z-axis translations that go with it on your `#parent` is enough to solve your problem.

You shouldn't displace your transformation origin when you've already displaced the elements that are going to move: the "slides" are already positionned relatively to the point z=0 of your `#parent`. So the rotations of `#parent` should be made relatively to this point as well.

Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nAeDc

**PS:** do you mind I keep this in my Experiments folder :) ? This is pretty cool !

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');

var degree = 0;

document.getElementById('rotate').addEventListener('click', function() {
  parent.style.transform = "rotateY(" + (degree+=36) + "deg)";
});
document.getElementById('active').addEventListener('click', function() {
    parent.style.transform = "";
    parent.classList.remove('active2');
    parent.classList.add('active');
});
document.getElementById('active2').addEventListener('click', function() {
    parent.style.transform = "";
    parent.classList.remove('active');
    parent.classList.add('active2');
});
```

```css
#parent {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: center center 0;

    transition: transform 1s linear;
}

#parent:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -3px 0 0 -3px;
  background: red;
}

#parent.active {
    transform: rotateY(-144deg);
}

#parent.active2 {
    transform: rotateY(-288deg);
}

.card {
    background: blue;
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: absolute;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    
    opacity: .5;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.card-1  { transform: rotateY( 0deg )   translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
.card-2  { transform: rotateY( 36deg )  translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
.card-3  { transform: rotateY( 72deg )  translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
.card-4  { transform: rotateY( 108deg ) translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
.card-5  { transform: rotateY( 144deg ) translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
.card-6  { transform: rotateY( 180deg ) translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
.card-7  { transform: rotateY( 216deg ) translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
.card-8  { transform: rotateY( 252deg ) translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
.card-9  { transform: rotateY( 288deg ) translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
.card-10 { transform: rotateY( 324deg ) translate3d(0, 0, 461px ); }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="card card-1">1</div>
    <div class="card card-2">2</div>
    <div class="card card-3">3</div>
    <div class="card card-4">4</div>
    <div class="card card-5">5</div>
    <div class="card card-6">6</div>
    <div class="card card-7">7</div>
    <div class="card card-8">8</div>
    <div class="card card-9">9</div>
    <div class="card card-10">10</div>
</div>
<button id="rotate">Rotate 1step</button>
<button id="active">Rotate</button>
<button id="active2">Rotate again</button>
```